# R List row name

Tags: r

I have a (one column) list called Test in R.

When I view it in R I get something like this:

```
> Test
                    Value
569                 N
1012                Y
4279                N
7588                N
3434                N
2408                Y
1958                Y
1251                Y
```

How do I reference the "row name"? I.e. 569, 1012, 4279 etc.

I want to find for example the Value at "row" 1012 (which is "Y" here). I've tried using Test[1], Test[,1] etc. but the first column isn't really a column. I don't know what it is. Hopefully this makes some kind of sense. I don't even know what to look for to find the solution to this.

Comment: Against your hopes, it doesn't really make sense.  It would help if you provided the output of `dput(Test)`.

Comment: `Test` doesn't look like a list to me. Sure this isn't a data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Test` *is* a data frame;

```
txt <- "                    Value
569                 N
1012                Y
4279                N
7588                N
3434                N
2408                Y
1958                Y
1251                Y
"
Test <- read.table(textConnection(txt), header = TRUE)
```

then,

```
> Test["1012", ]
[1] Y
Levels: N Y
```

will extract the required row.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Would have never figured that out. Thanks for the help. Much appreciated

Comment: @RGui I should probably add that you might do well to read the first few sections of [An Introduction to R]http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html --- one of the manuals that comes with R, to learn about subsetting in R and what the rules are.